# Invalid Access Token header - Twilio Voice IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I cloned this repo from Github which contains a short example of entering a phone number and calling that number with Twilio Voice SDK for IOS: https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios. I generated an access token following the instructions with the command line but I get an error message when I try to initiate a call.

The command I ran:

```
twilio token:voice --identity=identity --voice-app-sid=AP537f...
```

The token:

```
Copy/paste this voice token into your test application:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImN0e.....
```

This is what jwt.io gives back for the token:

```
1704129998",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "identity",
    "voice": {
      "incoming": {
        "allow": true
      },
      "outgoing": {
        "application_sid": "AP53...."
      }
    }
  },
  "iat": 1704129998,
  "exp": 1704133598,
  "iss": "SK...",
  "sub": "AC..."
}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you try again outside of IOS? Also, you may want to remove your account sid from your post - not super confidential but half of what is super confidential.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip with the account id. Can you specify what you mean by outside of IOS?

Comment: I mean use a different easier to setup development environment like c#, python, or php. It would also be helpful to know the error. Twilio will usually provide a pretty specific error or exception message. From the original post, I cannot understand if it is a Twilio error, an IOS error, or a browser error.